# AutoPostback on dropDownList issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this piece of code to check with user if it is ok to leave page without saving:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

window.onbeforeunload = !isPostBack && confirmExit;

function isPostBack() {
    return <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true":"false" %>
}

function confirmExit() {
     return "Some lame question for user. :)";     
}
</script>
```

There is a problem with pages which have dropDownLists and I must have AutoPostBack set to true. 
AutoPostBack=true results in annoying popup every time.
I've figured out how to check for postBack (thank you Google), but now I'm stuck.

There shouldn't be mistake, I have no idea when it comes to java script. I'm poor desktop programmer trying to learn something new.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is here, what do you mean annoying popup? Shouldn't the confirmExit() method do something like: `return confirm('Question?');`

Comment: he means the warning about re-posting the previously posted form.

Comment: You can't just rely on checking if the page has been "PostBack:ed". The IsPostBack will be true once a postback has occured, but the user can still try to leave the page for another page. You have to check why the page is unloading, i.e. by setting a client side variable using client code when the user causes a postback (a javascript onclick event handler on the controls causing postbacks).

Answer (score 1):

`window.onbeforeunload` is expected to be a function and not a bool value. You might have intended this, or similar:

```
if(<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true":"false" %>)
{
    window.onbeforeunload = function()
    {
        return "Some lame question for user. :)"; 
    };
}
```

BTW, another way to avoid the re-posting warning would be the post-redirect-get pattern (redirect to the same page that you posted to, from within the event handler on the server).

Answer (score 1):

onbeforeunload should store a function, not a boolean value, because it's a callback.

You could do something like :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!isPostBack && confirmExit) { 
       //leave page
    }
}
```